# Repeating a drawImage HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image that I would like to repeat without using multiply images.

```
var bg1 = function (speed) { // MOVEING IMAGES
    if (bg_moving) { // background
        bg.x-= 1 * speed; // SPEED
        ctx.drawImage(bg_image, bg.x, 0);
    }
}
```

http://developerdrive.developerdrive.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/header2.png

(Not my image, but example of a image that would repeat-x)

Answer (score 2):

You can draw it again as many times as you need. In this example it gets drawn five times to the right.

```
var repeat = 5;
var bg1 = function (speed) { // MOVING IMAGES
    if (bg_moving) { // background
        bg.x-= 1 * speed; // SPEED
        for (var i = 0; i < repeat; i++){
            ctx.drawImage(bg_image, bg.x + (i * bg.width), 0);
        }
    }
}
```